# Django, initial checked input

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I pre-check a `CheckboxInput` of a form?

I tried this in `__init__`:

```
self.fields['name_field'].widget.attrs['checked'] = 'checked'
```

But it doesn't work..

My field is a boolean field in model and in my form it's a checkbox input.

Comment: did you call the `super` in `__init__` ?

Comment: Have you tried `form = MyForm(initial={'name_field': True})` in the respective view?

Comment: I will try the value True. Edit : It don't works... :/